# Javascript - Which eslint jsdoc rule/setting to force either @private, @public or @protected

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc

Is there any eslint jsdoc rule/setting to force either `@private`, `@public` or `@protected`? With the module [eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc) there is no rule/setting to force it.

Following example should throw a eslint jsdoc error:

```
/**
 * @param {string} foo
 */
function quux (foo) {

}
```

This jsDoc should not accepted because `@private`, `@public` or `@protected` are not available.

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jsdoc/no-restricted-syntax` rule, disallowing blocks which don't have those access modifiers.

Add this to your eslint config file:

```
rules: {
  'jsdoc/no-restricted-syntax': ['error', {
    contexts: [
      {
        comment: 'JsdocBlock:not(JsdocBlock:has(JsdocTag[tag=/private|protected|public/]))',
        context: 'any',
        message: 'Access modifier tags must be present',
      },
    ]
  }
}
```